# SIGABRT when 'Running' app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ld, sigabrt

```
GDB: Program received signal "SIGABRT"
```

I'm running a problem with a few things according to the Build log, please could you shed light on the possibilities that these errors could be caused by. All help is appreciated.

Summary of project:

I have two projects which i have taken some .h, .m and .a files from one project folder, dragged them into the other project, then going through 
*Menu > Project > Add to project* I have imported them into the Static Library of the project.

Some lines of code I have blanked my details out for privacy.

Here are the errors I'm getting...

- `found branch-22 without store in _SOGLH`
- `found branch-22 without store in TrackerInterface::InstantiateTracker()`
- `ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myname/Desktop/*projectname*/*It's_a_dot_A_file*.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)`

I'm relatively new to Xcode so I'm not confident with some of the terms so please bear that in mind.

King Regards,
R.

Answer (score 0):

For the last error, it is quite self-explanatory: you are trying to include a library (`.a`) file that has been built for a different architecture.

Probably a library that has been built for OSX-32bits or OSX-64bits and that you are trying to use for iOS (which uses architectures armv6 & armv7).

Rebuild the library for the correct architecture (armv7) of if it is a third-party library, use the appropriate `.a` file for the appropriate architecture.